# GCD Function in VBA Returning Too Many Digits

Tags: vba, excel, greatest-common-divisor

I want to return a ratio in my Excel sheet using VBA. I have two columns of data: repaired defects and unrepaired defects. The ratio would be the number of defects a crew repaired to the number of defects they could not repair. I am using this function to find the GCD:

```
Function GCD(numerator, denominator)
    If denominator = 0 Then
        GCD = numerator
    Else 
        GCD = GCD(denominator, numerator Mod denominator)
    End If
End Function
```

Then I calculate it and print it in the Results page of my spreadsheet with:

```
Sheets("Results").Range("M" & iResults)/Value = RatioNum1 & ":" & RatioNum2
```

Where RatioNum1 and RatioNum2 are simply variables where I have stored Data1 / GCD and Data2 / GCD. My problem is that in Excel, say the ratio is 1 to 1, it prints the second number with an extra digit every time, in this example 1:01. Or if it's supposed to be 3:1, it prints 3:01 and so on.

Is this simply the way the function returns values or am I inadvertently adding the extra digit somewhere with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the zero in front of the second ratio number, simply use the `Int` function like this:

```
Sheets("Results").Range("M" & iResults)/Value = RatioNum1 & ":" & Int(RatioNum2)
```

Comment: I would also like to reiterate I am a beginner. The code you sent me worked great but when I ran it again it still was formatting strange. It was only after this that I realized that since I printed two numbers and a colon, excel automatically read it as a time. After I had it read it as a text, the numbers went away, but I appreciate your help nonetheless!

Comment: worthwhile pointing out why the error is happening. Without the qualification, Excel would be interpreting the x:y as a time, thus converting the minutes to something a bit more 'minutey' (3:01 instead of 3:1)

Comment: Thank you @AJD. That was exactly what was happening. I had to go in and make sure it was reading it in the way I wanted